# Cell data doesn't update

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm going through some tutorial for editing table cells whose data is stored in a server. Everything is working fine - I can edit a table cell and click on the "save" button, but if I go back to the table overview it's not updated. 
I've got 3 table fields:

- titleField
- authorField
- atextField

I don't know if the problem comes from this piece of code, but I suppose so. The tutorial example has just 2 fields, and I need 3 fields, but I don't know how to implement this piece of code for 3 textfields:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField { 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField == titleField) {
        [authorField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (titleField == authorField) {
        [self save];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I already tried `if (titleField == authorField == atextField)`, but the error message says: `Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'UITextField')`. I also tried `if (titleField == authorField && titleField == atextField && authorField == atextField){`and I don't get an error, but it doesn't change the fact that the data doesn't update the changes.

How should the code above look like?

Answer (score 2):

Those IF's dont have sense, you cannot do this:

```
if (titleField == authorField == atextField)
```

Because you are comparing the result of the first == with the textfield, hence the Comparison between pointer and integer error.

In the 2nd one,

```
if (titleField == authorField && titleField == atextField && authorField == atextField)
```

This is never going to get called, because the titleField cannot be 3 things at the same time.

My first thought would be doing something like this:

```
    if (textField == titleField) {
            [authorField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    else if ((textField == authorField){
            [atextField becomeFisrtResponder];
     else if (titleField == atextField) {
            [self save];
        }
```

I think this is what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, I get what you mean! 
Sadly, it still doesn't solve my problem. So the issue might be somewhere else I suppose. Thanks anyways.